# Power BI - Cell background color

Tags: powerbi, background-color

How can i set the color of any cell under some of the columns, within a Power BI table, which have text?  If a cell does not have text (blank, null, etc), then i want to leave it the white color (or no color).  Only cells with any kind of text in them need colored.  BTW, the text could be anything and there are thousands or more of variations of text in these cells.

I have tried using the conditional formatting, but that's not working for me, as i'm dealing with text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use measures in conditional formatting:

[image: 1]

Your measure could look like this:

```
If(
   ISBLANK(your_text_column_or_measure),"#FFFFFF", "#another_color"
)
```