# Change background color by text in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis

how can i change the background color based on text in power bi as per attach. For example, critical is red, reorder is yellow, ideal is green and etc.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this question. From my view it's pretty clear and the solution involves conditional formatting and a DAX measure.

Comment: @Miracle Polaris In tables you can use conditional formatting on "cell elements".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power BI - Cell background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960860/power-bi-cell-background-color)

Answer (score 1):

Use this **calculated column**

```
Color = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    'Table'[Status] = "Critical", "#FF0000",
    'Table'[Status] = "Ideal", "#008000"
)
```

Then you go to formatting of cell elements, Font color, based on Field value:

[image]

And the result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: hi, but can you share where you create that calculated column in power bi?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use conditional formatting for background color under 'Cell elements'.
Format/Cell elements/Background color/On

[image]

Background Color:

```
Background Color = SWITCH(TRUE(),
                    Table[Status] = "Critical", "#FF0000",
                    Table[Status] = "Reorder", "#FFFF00",
                    Table[Status] = "Ideal", "#00FF00",
                    Table[Status] = "Overflow", "#0000FF"
```

)
[image]